# xslt change parent -> child to child -> parent

Tags: xslt, transform, parent

I have a XML like this and need to change parent->child with their places:

```
<root>
    <testcase name="Case1">
        <testsuite>Suite1</testsuite>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Case2">
        <testsuite>Suite1</testsuite>
    </testcase>

    <testcase name="Case3">
        <testsuite>Suite2</testsuite>
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Case4">
        <testsuite>Suite2</testsuite>
    </testcase>
</root>
```

need to transform this to this xml:

```
<root>
    <testsuite name="Suite1">
        <testcase>Case1</testcase>
        <testcase>Case2</testcase>
    </testsuite>

    <testsuite name="Suite2">
        <testcase>Case3</testcase>
        <testcase>Case4</testcase>
    </testsuite>
</root>
```

Can anyone help to implement this ?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? For XSLT 2.0 you can use the for-each-group instruction, otherwise you need to look into the muenchian method.

Comment: Perhaps I need XSLT 1.0. As I have an XML file and need to open it with IE (transformed into html using XSL file).

Comment: If you need to transform it into HTML then there is no point in transforming  the data first - the XSLT processor in IE does not support double processing of results I don't think.

Comment: Actually I'm processing directly to HTML, just I wrote here a simple case to transform child to parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a grouping problem, and as with most grouping problems, the preferred approach (at least in XSLT 1.0) is to use Muenchian grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kSuite" match="testsuite" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
                      select="testcase/testsuite[generate-id() = 
                                                 generate-id(key('kSuite', .)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="testsuite">
    <testsuite name="{.}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kSuite', .)/.." />
    </testsuite>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="testcase">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<root>
  <testsuite name="Suite1">
    <testcase>Case1</testcase>
    <testcase>Case2</testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Suite2">
    <testcase>Case3</testcase>
    <testcase>Case4</testcase>
  </testsuite>
</root>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't, but the browser does not render the XML elements, just the text.

Answer (score 1):

With an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*/*" group-by=".">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/.."/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```